# Serializer for JSONField nested representation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my application there's a model that stores a configuration in one of its fields. The field is defined as `JSONField`. I have a strict structure that defines what content of this field should look like, but I'm struggling to find a way how to serialize it to validate data in API requests.

The solution that works for now, but does not validate what's inside `config_field`, is blindly accept anything that complies with being a `json` object:

A simplified version of my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    config_field = JSONField(...)
    ...
```

For the sake of this question here's a simplified version of the data structure stored in `config_field`:

```
{"some_config_int": 42, "some_config_vars": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}
```

And here's a simplified version of my serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        config_field = serializers.JSONField(required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ('config_field', ...)
```

What I'd like to achieve though is to have a serializer for the nested representation ([reference to DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)) of what's inside `config_field`. What I've tried so far (but does not work):

```
class ConfigVarsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

class ConfigFieldsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_config_int = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    some_config_vars = serializers.ListField(child=ConfigVarsSerializer,required=True)

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            config_field = ConfigFieldsSerializer(required=False)
            class Meta:
                model = MyModel
                fields = ('config_field', ...)
```

This way it will be optional to POST/PUT an object with a configuration, but if `config_field` is in the body of the request, the entire nested object should be provided.

Comment: When you say "but does not work", that's not really enough to go on.  What doesn't work about it?  What do you expect to happen which does not?  Is this about formatting, or about validation not being called, or something entirely different?

Comment: My bad, I submitted question with the code that I didn't edit fully, it was updated, please take a look

Comment: You still never stated what is wrong.  What is it about this solution that "does not work" for you?  Are you getting an error somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying several possible solutions I want to point out 2 simplest and most importantly those that ***do not require*** overriding `create` method for neither `MyModelSerializer` nor inner serializers:

1. Override field validation method for `config_field` in `MyModelSerializer`
2. Override `validate` method for entire object being serialized by `MyModelSerializer`

Serializers representing inner content of `config_field` would be the same for both solutions:

```
class ConfigVarsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

class ConfigFieldsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_config_int = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    some_config_vars = serializers.ConfigVarsSerializer(required=True, many=True)
```

> Note that `some_config_vars` stores list of objects, that's why `many=True`.

---

### Solution 1

Override field validation method for `config_field` in `MyModelSerializer`. In case of given example the final code of serializer would be:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        config_field = JSONField(required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ('config_field', ...)

        def validate_config_field(self, value):
            serializer = ConfigFieldsSerializer(data=value)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return value
```

This approach first validates `config_field` using default `JSONFieldSerializer` and raises exception if content isn't a valid `JSON` object.

If `JSONFieldSerializer` raises no exception `validate_custom_fields` is called and it passes content of field into `ConfigFieldsSerializer` and validates all content for itself and all nested serializers.

---

### Solution 2

Override `validate` method for entire object being serialized by `MyModelSerializer`. In case of given example the final code of serializer would be:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        config_field = JSONField(required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ('config_field', ...)

        def validate(self, attrs):
            config_field = attrs.get('config_field')
            if config_field:
                serializer = ConfigFieldsSerializer(data=config_field)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return attrs
```

This approach requires a little bit more code, but allows to combine validation of `config_field` with other related fields.

Comment: Hi @Stan Redoute. I tried your solution (1) and I noticed that if I send un-familiar field in  config_field json, it still used that value and assign it in the result json. For example, instead of sending 'some_config_int' or 'some_config_vars' I can send 'some_field', the validation will not throw exception and this field (json attribute) will be part of the config_field. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending data ***against the `config_field` field***, so, your data should include that key. So the payload should be as below

```
{"config_field": {"some_config_int": 42, "some_config_vars": ["foo", "bar"]}}
```

## Update-1

use ***`DictField()`*** in serializer as,

```
VALID_DICT_KEYS = ['foo_1']


class ConfigFieldsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_config_int = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    some_config_vars = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField(), required=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        some_config_vars = attrs['some_config_vars']
        keys_list = []
        for item in some_config_vars:
            keys_list.extend(list(item.keys()))
        unwanted_keys = set(keys_list) - set(VALID_DICT_KEYS)
        if unwanted_keys:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("raise error with some msg")
        return attrs


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    config_field = ConfigFieldsSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('config_field',)


data = {'config_field': {"some_config_int": 42, "some_config_vars": [{"foo_1": "bar"}, {"foo_2": "honey"}]}}
serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(True)
print(serializer.data)
```

Comment: if someone downvotes this answer, a comment is appreciated

Comment: You’ve simply copied code from my question and pasted a body of nested object that was given as example

Comment: Actually, the problem was not in your code sample, it's in the data you've passed into the serializer

Comment: If you read the question carefully you'll see that I'm trying to serialize what's inside the field. The field itself is obviously being submitted with other fields. The question is about serializing JSONField, not replacing it with a different data type.

Comment: Where did I replace with a different data type? I don't get that point. What I'm saying is, you are trying to serialize/validate the data in the wrong way. I hope my updated answer will help you @StanRedoute

Comment: I'm sorry, mate, I submitted wrong code snippet by mistake, I fixed the code, please take a look again. The issue is with objects nested in a list.

Comment: Great! This helps to validate whether the content is a dict though, is there a way to serialize what's inside the dict?

Comment: can you share valid and invalid dict?\

Comment: It's not a matter of whether the dict is valid or not, it's that I want to verify whether the inner structure of dict is the way I want it to be.

Comment: For example `{"foo_1": "bar"}` should work, but I don't want it to have any other keys

Comment: Which means the dict keys should be a subset of ***`VALID_DICT_KEYS`***, where  `VALID_DICT_KEYS` is a list of valid keys...right?

Comment: Override the **`validate()`** method to add complex validations. Anyway I've updated my answer @StanRedoute